# Impressão de etiqueta com código de barras em impressora Argox (USB)

Tags: java, impressão, código-de-barras

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde eu preciso gerar e imprimir código de barras em uma etiqueta através da impressora **Argox** com conexão USB.
Apesar de ser uma aplicação Web, o sistema rodará local, ou seja, o sistema tem acesso aos recursos de hardware da máquina. Cliente possui 2 modelos de impressora:

- Argox Cash Way (USB)
- Argox S-21 4 plus

Consegui encontrar alguns poucos tutoriais em java para impressoras Argox, apenas em impressoras com conexão Serial.

Minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

1. Existe diferença a nível de programação entre as impressoras serial e USB?
2. Alguém possui material de apoio para desenvolvimento específico em java para este tipo de impressora?

Comment: você conseguiu solucionar a sua duvida? Me encontro na mesma situação.

Comment: Consegui sim @DevAgil, comentei como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema pode ser resolvido de diversas formas, tudo depende de como você precisa fazer a impressão.

Caso o sistema que você esteja desenvolvendo seja em delphi, a situação fica Muito mais fácil, existem componentes que deixam o trabalho muito mais fácil, como o ACBR: http://acbr.sourceforge.net/drupal/

Entretanto, o sistema em que estou desenvolvendo, citado na pergunta à cima, era uma aplicação JAVA EE rodando em um servidor local, na máquina em que a impressora estava conectada.

Minha primeira tentativa foi gerar um arquivo PDF, e enviar este arquivo para impressão na impressora que estava conectada, entretanto, esses modelos de impressora argox que eu estava utilizando **NÃO** aceitam arquivos pdf. Porém, percebi que se eu apenas gerasse o PDF, e imprimisse via S.O, a impressora conseguia imprimir.

Só que o requisito do projeto, era que a impressão fosse feita automaticamente, sem a interação do usuário. A situação a cima já foi o suficiente para entender que o Sistema Operacional conseguia resolver a situação da impressão.

**Porém se não posso mandar um PDF, como vou definir o layout?**

Essas impressoras costumam ter uma linguagem própria para definir o layout das aplicações, no caso deste modelo da Argox, era a linguagem **PPLB**, basta procurar pela documentação para aprender a criar os layouts.

**Código para Imprimir**

O código abaixo, faz o seguintes passos:

1. Detecta o S.O
2. Injeta um comando no terminal para realizar a impressão

O Arquivo etiqueta.txt é um arquivo que foi gerado anteriormente na linguagem PPLB, com os valores a serem impressos na etiqueta, ele esta salvo na raiz do projeto, você pode criar seu proprio etiqueta.txt com somente um "Olá mundo" e executar o comando no terminal do seu S.O para testar a impressão.

```
public class Etiqueta {

    //Imprime a etiqueta de acordo com o sistema operacional
    public static void imprimirEtiqueta() throws IOException {
        if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
            try {
                String[] command = {"cmd",};
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                new Thread(new ThreadSyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
                new Thread(new ThreadSyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
                PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
                stdin.println("type etiqueta.txt > ImpressoraCompartilhadaNoWindows"); //No windows, você precisa compartilhar a impressora na rede e passar o nome dela no comando para imprimir
                stdin.close();
                int returnCode = p.waitFor();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new ErrorPrintingLabelException("Erro ao imprimir: Etiqueta ou impressora não encontrada. Erro: " 
                        + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX){
            String[] args = new String[] {"/bin/bash", "-c", "cat etiqueta.txt > /dev/usb/lp1"}; //no linux é mais simples, apenas passe o local da impressora
            Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();        
        } else {
            System.out.println("O recurso de impressão de etiquetas não é compatível com este S.O");
        }
    }
```

Thread para a impressão:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

class ThreadSyncPipe implements Runnable {
  public ThreadSyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
      istrm_ = istrm;
      ostrm_ = ostrm;
  }
  public void run() {
      try {
          final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          for (int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1; ){
              ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  private final OutputStream ostrm_;
  private final InputStream istrm_;
}
```

Apesar de ser um grande workaround, funciona super bem em produção, não tive problemas com a impressão.